# Application that uses Django models need to be a Django app?

Tags: python, django

What is the definition of a Django application? Any application that uses Django features, such as orm and url-view mapping?

I ask because I have a component which has 2 sub-components: a web service server and a standalone application. The web service server uses Django views to map url to request handlers. The web service server and the application use Django models and a database managed by Django. The web service server obviously needs to be a Django application. The standalone application must be a Django application as well?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, importing your models is enough, as long as you have Django installed and correctly configured.

Comment: Yes, I use this process in production, with standalone apps accessing the database using the Django ORM.